# how can you open a new page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, window.location

i have code that sets

```
window.location.href = [someurl]
```

but i want to have it open up in a new tab.  Is there anyway to have the above code include

```
target="_blank"
```

from javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes

```
window.open([someurl], "_blank");
```

or since _blank is the default

```
window.open([someurl]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.open()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

`window.location.href` just changes the location of the current window.

Answer (score 1):

To open a new window, you will need to use yet another ready-made JavaScript function. Here is what it looks like:

```
window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2')
```

This is the function that allows you to open a new browser window for the viewer to use. Note that all the names and attributes are separated with a comma rather than spaces. Here is what all the stuff inside is:

1. `'url to open'` This is the web address of the page you wish to appear in the new window.
2. `'window name'` You can name your window whatever you like, in case you need to make a reference to the window later.
3. `'attribute1,attribute2'` As with alot of other things, you have a choice of attributes you can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.open([someurl], [target="_blank"]);
```

sould be work.